# Are these cases of genuine help or someone trying to inflate their commit count?

Tags: community-official-site

I maintain a few modules from drupal.org, and lately I've noticed the phenomenon of people who inflate their commit count, who come to an in-development module page, suggest a patch that consists of very simple standards-compliance work (indentations, stray spaces, adding a generic README file, etc.), and ask you to commit it.

Any contribution is nice, of course, but I go to the user's profile, and see that they have hundreds of similar one-off, minimal-contribution commits, and the "work" appears to be a case of artificially inflating their contribution score.

My questions are:

1. How does one benefit from inflating their commit count?
2. Are there legitimate cases of someone who wants to be helpful, even if the commit is simple?
3. If I suspect someone is inflating their commit count, how can I report this?

Comment: I don't, particularly with the second example. That person is one of dozens of drive-by-patch (almost botlike) posters where the entire point is to game the system, pad the commits, and make companies show up higher in the marketplace. I miss the days of real code review - anymore it just seems like "typo in readme, patch attached" sort of posts, which don't add any overall value to a module or theme. I'd rather see metrics on the "value" - your company may have 3000 commits attributed to it, but lets see quality over quantity.

Comment: Sorry but this isn’t the kind of question we can address here - there’s no possibility of a single, objective answer, and any given responses could only be based on opinion on not hard facts (something Q+A relies on)

Comment: @Clive , I have edited the question to move it away from being too opinion-based. The central question still is "How to tell the difference between legitimate patches versus people trying to game the marketplace?" Kevin's comment was helpful in this regard Let me know how else I can improve the question.

Comment: I still think this is an opinated, leading question. Searching google for "commit hustler" results in this same page so it's obviously neologism. Whether or not someone is "gaming the system" and other questions that follow from that is something that should be brought up on drupal.org, not a Q+A knowledge base.

Comment: @ShawnConn I understand. Would changing that particular phrase to "gaming the system" be sufficient, or would you like to see something further?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I've used a different term to improve readability.

Comment: Please do raise it on drupal.org.

Comment: @Kevin Done: https://www.drupal.org/forum/general/general-discussion/2018-09-12/are-these-cases-of-genuine-help-or-someone-trying-to

Comment: @MikeNolan Merci beaucoup!

Comment: From that thread, I was recommended to take up the issue with the webmasters. When I get an answer from them, I will post it here.

Comment: @Clive Please open this so I can post an answer. I have spoken with some additional developers and one of the companies involved, and have some additional information. Otherwise, if the "opinionated" issue is still present, we can delete this question.

Comment: Drupal.org really does seem like a more appropriate place for this, there still isn’t a single objective way to address anything other than the 3rd question - glad you found the answer you were looking for either way :)

Comment: @Clive No worries then. We can close this question (or leave it on hold) in that case.